# Conditionally Change Icons for Array Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my simple code to call and display my posts

```
/// My API Data Call ///
getPosts() {
    axios
      .get("myAPIDATA")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response.data.response
        });
      });
  }

// Displays data from API call successfully //
{this.state.posts.map((post, index)=> {
        return (
         <View key={index}>
          <Text>
            {post.category},
            {post.content}
          </Text>
         </View>
        )
      })}
```

I have 4 total categories that posts can fall under in post.category: A, B, C, D. If the post category is "A" I'd like to display a specific icon, if the category is "B" I'd like to display a different icon. At what point in my code would I define the conditional icons? During the getPosts or during the posts.map?

Comment: The map code is probably in the component's `render()` method? Please include it for completeness. The most direct way to do what you want would be to define a method/function called `iconForCategory` that takes a category and returns the appropriate icon component (a `switch` statement or an object mapping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During `post.map`, you can try something like this:

```
const ICONS = {
  A: "icon-a",
  B: "icon-b",
  C: "icon-c",
  D: "icon-d"
};

// Displays data from API call successfully //
{
  this.state.posts.map(post => {
    return (
      <View key={post.id}>
        <Text>
          {post.category},{post.content}
        </Text>
        <Icon type={ICONS[post.category]} />
      </View>
    );
  });
}
```